# Why is there $(2,3)$ corner coordinates on the graph, using this function: $f(x)=2x-1+|x-2|?$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, absolute-value

Currently I am studying about absolute values and I had to consider this function and draw it's graph:

$$f(x)=2x-1+|x-2|$$

I helped myself with symbolab, here is the link: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3D2x-1%2B%5Cleft%7Cx-2%5Cright%7C/?origin=button

I understood everything about getting the $x$ coordinate $(-1, 0)$ and $y$ coordinate $(0,1)$ but I don't see where did $(2,3)$ corner coordinates come from or what does it mean - could anyone please tell that to me$?$

I am also including the picture: [graph and it's coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7dRv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$|x - 2| = \begin{cases}
            x - 2 & \text{if $x \geq 2$}\\
            -(x - 2) & \text{if $x < 2$}
            \end{cases}
$$
the function $f(x) = 2x - 1 + |x - 2|$ can be defined piecewise as 
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \begin{cases}
        2x - 1 + x - 2 & \text{if $x \geq 2$}\\
        2x - 1 - (x - 2) & \text{if $x < 2$}
        \end{cases}\\
     & = \begin{cases}
         3x - 3 & \text{if $x \geq 2$}\\
         x + 1 & \text{if $x < 2$}
         \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Thus, if $x > 2$, the graph has slope $3$, while the graph has slope $1$ if $x < 2$.  The graph has a corner at $x = 3$ since the slope to the right of $x = 2$ is different from the slope to the left of $x = 2$.

Answer (score 3):

$(2,3)$ is clearly a point on the graph because it satisfies the equation:

$$3=2\cdot2-1+|2-2|$$

The reason why the graph has an angle at that point is because it is the minimum of the second part of the expression, $|x-2|.$ Compare this to the minimum of the function $|x|$ itself at $x=0.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And now I just saw why I was confused! Because x and y lines doesn't have the same measurement! I draw the graph on my paper and saw that the line is actually straight!

Comment: Em, I don't think it *should* be straight.

Comment: http://puu.sh/m9fWM/07e622f11d.jpg it looks like this when I draw it - why it shouldn't be straight?

Comment: You're really missing a part - try including a point beyond $x=2,$ like $(3,6)$